# line-breaks between every 2 row

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm quit new with mysql, and php but everytime i'm learning.
For a friend of my I'm building a website with a small pricing-list on it.
The prices are from a database, but I now want to create a empty line bewtween the 2nd and the 3th line, but I don't know how to do that.

I use the following code to receive the information from the database;

```
<table id="nails" class="prijzen">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nails</th>
            <th>Price first visite</th>
            <th>Regular price</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <?php
        // while ($row = $queryNails->fetch_assoc()) {  
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $regularNails->fetch_assoc())
        {
           if($i%3 == 0)
           {
              echo "<tr class='even'>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['name'] ."</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['prijs'] ."</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['actie_prijs'] ."</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
           }
           else
           {
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['name'] ."</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['prijs'] ."</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['actie_prijs'] ."</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
           }
        $i++;
    ?>
    <tbody>

        <?php 
            }
        ?> 
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
```

I now have every odd-line a styling, but that is not something I like. I would like to create a sort of group of the output.

Hope someone can help me with that. If more information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Could be as simple as `echo "<td>" . $row['prijs'] ."</td>" . "<br>";` --- add more `<br>` if you want more spacing. Unless I've misunderstood.

Comment: I already tried that but that doesn't do the job unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please stop suggestion to enter a `<br />` in between lines. That's not gonna work at all, tables-101: Everything not placed in a `td` will be placed in before the table. So all you get is a bunch of empty lines **before** the whole table.

The code is allready there (if you want it before *every* 3rd row:

```
if($i%3 == 0)
{
    // The code right here will only run when $i / 3  is exactly 0 (3,6,9,etc)
    echo '<tr><td colspan="3">Blank line</td></tr>';

    echo "<tr class='even'>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['prijs'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['actie_prijs'] ."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

---

If you only want it *once* before the 3rd row, make this the first code in your while:

```
if($i==3){ echo '<tr><td colspan="3">Blank line</td></tr>'; }
```

---

The `%` is modulus. It gives you how much is left after getting the max amount of whole divisions:

```
echo 1 %3 = 1; 
echo 2 %3 = 2; 
echo 3 %3 = 0; // exactly dividable by 3
echo 4 %3 = 1; 
echo 5 %3 = 2; 
echo 6 %3 = 0;  // exactly dividable by 3
```

Comment: Thanx Martijn. Also that about the breaklines... I tried that also many in many ways but al the linebreak become on top of my table.
Eventhoug I tried your code but stil not working. I think i'm missing something but not sure why. Here is my code; [link]http://codeshare.io/NH7jB

With this code I don't get any results.

Comment: you changes `$row` to `$i` dont do that.

Comment: I did this, but then I have on every 2nd line the text blank line (that I understand) but now I miss alot of records. My database has 10 rows, but I only see 4 of them.. I have update my codeshare-link

Comment: And now you've removed the else from your code.... Just use the code in your topic, and add my lines to it.

Comment: GREAT.. that runs smoothly. Now I try to figure out how this actualy works, but that will be alright.

Comment: Please upvote the answer if you think it helped. About how it works, check the last part of my answer